# PHP 5.4: (new foo)->bar()

Tags: php, oop

it might be a newbie question, but does this PHP 5.4 feature

> *"Added class member access on instantiation (e.g. (new foo)->bar()) support."*

means that `Class::factory('some_class_name')` will be gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. A factory usually does a few things; *first*, it decides which kind of object to return based on some conditions, *second*, it generally handles dependencies too. That's to say that if A needs B, you request A from the factory, and B will be passed along to it in creation.
You can't do that with the `(new Foo)->bar()`.

What's more, is that the factory will return an object, which you can do dynamically now anyway:

```
$foo = new $classname;
```

Having a syntax like `($foo = new Foo)->bar()` is helpful for the situations where you want to execute a method right after creation, or if you're only ever executing one method on the object anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about dependency injection too after posting the question. Can you explain more on "which kind of object to return"? Btw, `(new foo)->bar()` is very nice for method chaining :) Like `(new foo)->bar()->execute()->get_array()`.

Comment: check [the description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) of the pattern; "Like other creational patterns, it deals with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created." It's generally the Factory that decides which class is returned, the requester is blissfully unaware.